# Cannot open Xcode project on a new Mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I think I have made a bit of a mistake here.

I designed an app a few months ago and even got it in the App Store. Since then I have purchased a new mac. I copied my Xcode project file across to my new Mac.

I've just come back to it for the first time in months and nothing opens. I sometimes get a cannot be parsed warning. Even looking at the file sizes I think there are all just empty files. When I try and open them in TextEdit they are just empty.

Any ideas anyone, I have a particular .swift file that I really need to open.

Comment: `Even looking at the file sizes I think there are all just empty files` if that's true for the files you need, there is likely something wrong with the way the files were copied. There's no XCode magic working with empty files

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files are empty on your old Mac. If they are empty on your old Mac then the data has been lost, there is nothing you can do.

If the files are correct on your old Mac then something went wrong when you transferred the data. Therefore just try copying them over again.

If the first situation that I stated is true then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not retrieve the original files from your other Mac?

> copy and paste

Would imply that you can. Maybe you should attempt to copy the files again, alternatively, if you just need the one .swift file you could probably copy the text from it and put it into plaintext and then copy that back out into a new xcode project if xcode is having such trouble opening that particular file.

Are you sure that you're not missing out some details? Seems almost too easy to answer this one.

Comment: Unfortunately I can no longer copy and paste as I have sold the old Mac several months ago. I can open the .swift file in Xcode but it is just blank. Same situation when I open it in TextEdit. I do have the original .xcarchive and .ipa but I don't think they can help me here?

Comment: Can you run `ls -ltra` in the directory that the .swift file is in and show us the output?

Comment: Another suggestion: do you have time machine running on your current Mac, or any backups from your old one? Maybe you could try digging through them to find an old version of the file that hasn't lost it's data?

Comment: Thanks Michael. not sure how to run the ls -ltra but cant see anything like that in the folder. I purchased a Time Machine when i purchased my new Mac, i didn't own own when i had my old one so no backup available. I think i will have to face facts that i have lost the info i need. thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to do it in Terminal. Although I feel like guiding you down that path is probably not going to get us anywhere considering you didn't know how to run the command in the first place. I think you might be right, the file is gone. Although, it may be worth checking anywhere that you may have files stored online, Dropbox, BitBucket, Github, even your emails? You may have sent it to someone via email or even to yourself? Maybe you can find at least something.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yes i will have a look elsewhere. seem to remembering copying the code into a Word document at some point. I'm still all relatively new to this and learning still.

Comment: @James-Hunt, I feel. Backups - particularly for production code - aren't just *suggested* but *required*. (And yeah, I know you know that now.) Look into what Xcode already has - Source Control - and my personal recommendation (there are others) look into **git* along with Github. (No link, it's very well-known and you'll find it.) Cloud backups also help greatly (like GitHub but you can brute-force things like iCloud). Bottom line, thanks for letting me know it's been a week since I backed up what I'm currently working on. We've all had that moment.